# Problem with showing/outputting Nat type in a function that converts integers to Nats

Tags: function, haskell, types, error-handling

I am currently learning about types in Haskell, and a given example in the book is to define the data of Nat by two constructors, one for zero, and another one for a constructor. As depicted here:

```
data Nat = Zero| Suc Nat
```

Also, I want to define a functions that converts a non-negative integer to a Nat and vice versa. I have written the following code:

```
nat2int:: Nat-> Int
nat2int Zero=0
nat2int (Suc n)= 1+ nat2int n

int2nat:: Int-> Nat
int2nat 0=Zero
int2nat n = Suc (int2nat (n-1))
```

However, whenever I execute the command

```
 int2nat 0
```

in the terminal, the following errors appears:

> - No instance for (Show Nat) arising from a use of `print'

> - In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

What does this error mean? and how to solve it? In general, I notice that whenever I define a new data type, and define functions that output objects of this newly defined data when I execute one of these functions, it gives me the same errors.

Comment: "No instance for (`Show T`)" means "I don't know how values of type `T` should be converted to string so I can print them". Often, declaring the type `T` with `... deriving (Show)` is enough to provide a basic conversion. In any case, one can instead code their custom `Show` instance to define how the type values should be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “No instance for `(Show T)`” means “I don't know how values of type `T` should be converted to string so I can print them”. Often, declaring the type `T` with `... deriving (Show)` is enough to provide a basic conversion. – [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi)

```
data Nat = Zero | Suc Nat
 deriving (Show)
```

In the (seldom) cases where this auto-generated `Show` instance does not behave like you want, you can always implement it yourself. It can be as simple as

```
data Nat = Zero | Suc Nat

instance Show Nat where
  show Zero = "Zero"
  show (Suc n) = "(Suc "++show n++")"
```

...however this is actually both inefficient (because of [Schlemiel](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) string [concatenation](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/data-structures.html#data.dlist)) and inelegant because we're blindly putting parentheses around the `n` whether or not it's needed. The preferred way to manually write `Show` instances is this style:

```
instance Show Nat where
  showsPrec _ Zero = ("Zero"++)
  showsPrec p (Suc n) = showParen (p>10) $ ("Suc "++) . showsPrec 11 n
```

(This is equivalent to the `deriving Show` version.)

By using `showsPrec 11 n` for the recursive call, I'm signalling that this `show` is used in a tighly binding (function application) setting, and therefore must add parentheses unless it is the already atomic `Zero` case. It won't, however, add outer parentheses if it is only shown in a context like `(Suc Zero, Suc (Suc Zero))`, because there's no need here.

You can also make `Show` instance a bit smarter, for instance it could make sense to avoid nesting of parentheses entirely and instead showing the version with composition operators, like

```
   Suc.Suc.Suc.Suc$Zero
```

which is more readable IMO. However, there is a near-mandatory convention that whatever you show *must* be valid Haskell code and should evaluate to the same value you originally used, so don't be tempted to make it super-succinct but non-Haskell syntax.

Comment: If you want an unconventional `Show` instance to improve readability, why not go all the way with `instance Show Nat where showsPrec p n = showParen (p>10) $ ("int2nat "++) . (show (nat2int n) ++)`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yeah, I thought about suggesting that, but it would perhaps be a bit counterproductive for the purpose of debugging Peano-arithmetic algorithms.